# Loop through one array and find value in a subarray of a different multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search, foreach

I'm beating my head against the wall on this!

I have two arrays:

```
$questionArray = Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [QueID] => 53
            [QueType] => Map question
            [QueText] => Where do you live?
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [QueID] => 55
            [QueType] => Multi selection
            [QueText] => What's your favorite car?
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [QueID] => 59
            [QueType] => Multi selection
            [QueText] => What's your favorite fruit?
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [QueID] => 54
            [QueType] => Single selection
            [QueText] => What's your favorite color?
        )
)

$answerArray = Array(
    [52264f64c9482] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [QueID] => 53
                    [QueType] => Map question
                    [Lat] => 41.86
                    [Lng] => -87.77
                    [AnsText] => 
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [QueID] => 55
                    [QueType] => Multi selection
                    [Lat] => 
                    [Lng] => 
                    [AnsText] => Chevy
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [QueID] => 54
                    [QueType] => Single selection
                    [Lat] => 
                    [Lng] => 
                    [AnsText] => Green
                )
        )
    [522a522e9f41f] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [QueID] => 53
                    [QueType] => Map question
                    [Lat] => 51.41
                    [Lng] => -27.21
                    [AnsText] => 
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [QueID] => 55
                    [QueType] => Multi selection
                    [Lat] => 
                    [Lng] => 
                    [AnsText] => Ford
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [QueID] => 59
                    [QueType] => Multi selection
                    [Lat] => 
                    [Lng] => 
                    [AnsText] => Banana
                )
        )
    [522a527ec0115] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [QueID] => 54
                    [QueType] => Single selection
                    [Lat] => 
                    [Lng] => 
                    [AnsText] => Blue
                )
        )
)
```

I am trying to loop through each array in $answerArray and then for each question array in $questionArray display the answer if there is one in a subarray of the $answerArray or if there is no matching answer in a subarray of the $answerArray return a "No answer" value. So if the script worked it would take the two arrays above and return:

Where do you live?:
    Lat - 41.86
    Lng - -87.77
What's your favorite car? - Chevy
What's your favorite fruit? - No Answer
What's your favorite color? - Green

Where do you live?:
    Lat - 51.41
    Lng - -27.21
What's your favorite car? - Ford
What's your favorite fruit? - Banana
What's your favorite color? - No Answer

Where do you live?:
    Lat - No Answer
    Lng - No Answer
What's your favorite car? -  No Answer
What's your favorite fruit? - No Answer
What's your favorite color? - Blue

I'm getting nowhere, the closest i've managed is:

```
foreach ($answerArray as $ansArray) {
    foreach ($questionArray as $queArray) {
        foreach ($ansArray as $ansItemArray) {
            if ($ansItemArray['QueID'] == $queArray['QueID']) {
                $result = $ansItemArray;
                if ($result['SQueType']== 'Map question') {
                    echo $ansItemArray['QueText'].' - '.$result['Lat'].'</br>';
                    echo $ansItemArray['QueText'].' - '.$result['Lng'].'</br>';
                } else {
                    echo $ansItemArray['QueText'].' - '.$result['AnsText'].'</br>';
                }
            } else {
                $result = array();
                if ($result['SQueType']== 'Map question') {
                    echo $ansItemArray['QueText'].' - No Answer</br>';
                    echo $ansItemArray['QueText'].' - No Answer</br>';
                } else {
                    echo $ansItemArray['QueText'].' - No Answer</br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</br></br>';
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required:

- Format User Supplied Answers
- Indicate unanswered questions for the user

Basically, it is a a single pass down the 'supplied answers'.

We need to indicate which questions were not answered. The way i did that is to have a 'state vector' of all the questions and unset them as they are answered. Report on the ones that remain.

Working code: [CodePad.org](http://codepad.org/RMZsFRTV)

Driving Code:

```
foreach ($answerArray as $id => $oneSetOfAnswers) {

    $unasweredQuestions = array();  // need a copy as it is a 'state vector'
                                    // of 'processed questions for this individual.
    foreach($questionArray as $oneQuestion) {
        $unasweredQuestions[$oneQuestion['ueID']] = $oneQuestion;
    }

    // process the answers...
    echo '<br />', '[' . $id . ']';

    foreach ($oneSetOfAnswers as $id => $oneAnswer) {


        $queId = $oneAnswer['QueID'];

        $theAnswers = getAnswer($unasweredQuestions[$queId], $oneAnswer);

        // remove from the list
        unset($unasweredQuestions[$queId]);

        // show answers
        foreach($theAnswers as $oneLine) {
            echo '<br />', $oneLine;
        }
    }

    // show the unansweredQuestions
    foreach ($unasweredQuestions as $question) {
        echo '<br />', $question['ueText'] .' : no answer supplied.';
    }
}
```

Function to extract the answers to one question.

```
/**
 *
 * @param type $question
 * @param type $oneAnswer
 * @return array ready to print
 */
function getAnswer($question,  $oneAnswer)
{
    $useAnsText =    strpos(strtolower($question['ueType']), 'multi') !== false
                  || strpos(strtolower($question['ueType']), 'single') !== false;
    $q = $question['ueText'];

    if ($useAnsText) {
        return array($q . ' : '. $oneAnswer['AnsText']);
    }

    // ignore standard stuff and assume whatever remains is wanted
    $ignore = array('AnsText', 'QueID', 'QueType');

    $answer = array($q);

    foreach($oneAnswer as $id => $response) {
        if (in_array($id, $ignore)) {
            continue;
        }

        $answer[] = $id .' : '. $response;
    }
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was not even in the same ballpark with where i was going. This is hugely helpful and works like a charm. Thank you again!